# Show success or error messages in Ajax response to Wordpress custom registration form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this custom form inside a Wordpress page template

```
<?php if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
if(get_option('users_can_register')) { 
    if($_POST){
        $username = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['user_login']);
        if(empty($username)) {
            echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />You have to fill in the username.";
            exit();
        }
        $email = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['user_email']);
        if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $email)) {
            echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />please use a calid e-mailadress.";
            exit();
        }

        //$random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
        $pass1 = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['pass1']);
        $pass2 = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['pass2']);
        if ($pass1 != $pass2){
            echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Error..</strong></span><br /><br />please use a passwords don't match.";
                exit();

        }
        $random_password = $pass1;
        $status = wp_create_user( $username, $random_password, $email );
        if ( is_wp_error($status) )
            echo "<span style='color:#FF0000'><strong>Feil..</strong></span><br /><br />Username allready exist. please try another one.";
        else {
            $from = get_option('admin_email');
            $headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
            $subject = "Registration ok!";
            $msg = "Welcome, you are now registered. Here is your username and password.\Info:\Username: $username\Password: $random_password";
            wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers );
            echo "<strong>You are now registered. An e-mail is now sent to you with your username and password..";
        }

        exit();

    } else { ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" id="registerform" class="col-xs-12" name="registerform">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <p>
                        <label for="user_login">Username</label>
                        <input id="user_login" class="input" type="text" size="20" value="" name="user_login">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="user_email">Email</label>
                        <input id="user_email" class="input" type="email" size="25" value="" name="user_email">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Password <input type="password" name="pass1" size="25" value="">
                        Repeat Password <input type="password" name="pass2" size="25" value="">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input id="wp-register" class="button-primary pull-right col-xs-12 col-md-3" type="submit" value="Register" name="wp-submit" tabindex="103">
                    <input type="hidden" value="/login-area/?action=register&success=1" name="redirect_to">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">                         
        jQuery("#wp-register").click(function() {
            var input_data = jQuery('#registerform').serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",
                data: input_data,
                success: function(data){
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status); // I would like to get what the error is
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
        </script>
<?php }
} else ?>
    Already registered? Login to your account with the form in the sidebar.
<?php } else { ?>
You are already logged in...
<?php } ?>
```

The PHP seems to work fine as when I console log it I get the right message when there is an error.

How can I show these errors inside the Ajax success or error functions?

The code I'm using always seems to always get to the success function even if there are some errors.

I would like to know what errors there are and print a message with the type of error somewhere on the page and if it's successful I'd like to print a successful message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @websupporter I managed to find a solution to my problem.

I have used this inside my Ajax function:

```
success: function(data){
    jQuery(data).find('.message').appendTo('#login-error');
}
```

And in the php code I have done this:

```
...
if(empty($username)) {
    echo "<span class='message error'>Please enter username.</span>";
    exit();
}
...
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: you should mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show these errors inside the Ajax success or error functions?

The jQuery error is triggered, when the request itself fails, for example timeout and others. See [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

The error messages, which are produced by PHP appear only on request success.

To display these, you could do for example:

```
            success: function(data){
                jQuery( data ).appendTo( 'body' );
            }
```

It will need some styling though :)

EDIT:
Since in your script it is possible, the whole `form`-element will be outputted, you can prevent this by using regular expressions in the `success`-callback:

```
        success: function(data){
            if( ! data.match( /<form/ ) )
                jQuery( data ).appendTo( 'body' );
        }
```

So you can use regular expressions to prevent appending output, you might not want to output.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried that but it appends the entire page. Is it possible to only append the error or success messages?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I add that nothing happens. The post request works but nothing shows on the page. It feels like I'm almost there..! So frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem. Any of above didn't work for me. Please make sure you set the dataType of your ajax call to 'html' not 'json'

Sample code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    data: { data: data, action: 'jseditajax' }
})
.done(function(response) {
    response = response.slice(0, - 1); // removing 0 at last string position
    response = JSON.parse(response); // string to JSON

    console.log(response);
});
```

And in your PHP file you can simply -

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

I hope this helps!